# Get message of notification and send to the activity

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Here is i am creating notification with the message **"wake up wake up !!!"**
    What i want to do when notification comes on particular time and user clicks on it i need to get that message **"wake up wake up !!!"** and send to **SnoozeActivity** where i am creating custom alert dialog and i want to show that message into that dialog

```
        alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, SnoozeActivity.class), 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("wake up wake up !!!"))
                .setContentText(msg).setAutoCancel(true);


        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        alarmNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
```

But i am not able to figure out how to get the message/data of clicked notification and send to next activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Intent` can carry data which you attach via `Intent.putExtra()`like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SnoozeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("com.example.mycoolapp.MYDATA", "wake up wake up !!!");
```

Then you continue with

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

In the `onCreate()` method of your `SnoozeActivity`, you can query the `Intent` for extras:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("com.example.mycoolapp.MYDATA"))
{
     String myText = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.mycoolapp.MYDATA");
}
```

It's recommended that the keys you use for `Intent` extras start with your package name.

**NOTE** not every kind of data is possible with `putExtra()`, please see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double[]%29)

Comment: getting null using this

Comment: @Dhiraj - forgot "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT", works now in my sample